# Visual Studio 2015 - License information says no "license information needed" but it's wrong

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2015, devart, dotconnect, licenses.licx

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with the latest devart dotConnect components (Version=9.4.348.0).

When I include a reference (dll) which uses the devart components internally in a C#-project it should be possible to fix the license information like this:
[image]

But since Visual Studio 2015 I get the following message:
[image]

("License is not needed. Application does not have a reference to Devart.Data.Oracle.")

But at runtime I get oracle exceptions because the license information is missing.

It works if I directly include the devart-components (dlls) in my project (even if not needed) and compile afterwards.

But shouldn't it work by fixing the license information as usually? Has someone the same problem here? Thx in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

By design, the License Information dialog looks (and looked) for direct Devart.* references only.

If we can assist you any further, please contact us via https://www.devart.com/company/contactform.html.